# Why do I try to call two fucntions in one if statement, but it ignores the other function after the first is completed? (C++)

Tags: c++

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours, poring over threads and videos trying to figure something out about this code. It will not compile unless I put "int" before calling my encrypt and decrypt functions in my if statements. If I do this, however, the program terminates before it gets to the encrypt/decrypt portion and acts as if it does not exist. Otherwise, it gives me such errors as "undefined reference to encrpyt();". I've read guides on calling functions, but it seems I can't get this to work. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int readNumber();
int encrypt();
int decrypt();
char choice;


int main()
{
cout << endl; 

cout << "Please select one of the following: " << endl;

cout << "1. Encrypt a number " << endl;

cout << "2. Decrypt a number " << endl; 

cout << endl;

cout << "Enter choice: ";

cin >> choice; 

cout << endl;


if (choice == '1')
{
    readNumber();
    encrypt();
}


else if (choice == '2')
{
    readNumber();
    decrypt();
}


else 
{
    cout << "Invalid choice. Try again. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

}

int readNumber()
{
int number;

cout << "Enter the four digit number: ";

cin >> number;


if (number > 9999)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please input a four digit, non-negative number. " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return readNumber();
} 


cout << endl;

return 0;


}

int encrypt(int number)
{
    int Num1,Num2,Num3,Num4;

Num1 = number / 1000;
Num2 = number / 100 - 10*Num1;
Num4 = number%10;
Num3 = (number%100 - Num4) / 10;


cout << "The encrypted number is: "
     << (Num4 + 7)%10
     << (Num3 + 7)%10
     << (Num2 + 7)%10
     << (Num1 + 7)%10
     << endl; 
        return 0;
 }

int decrypt(int number)
{
int Num1,Num2,Num3,Num4;

Num1 = number / 1000;
Num2 = number / 100 - 10*Num1;
Num4 = number%10;
Num3 = (number%100 - Num4) / 10;


cout << "The decrypted number is: "
     << (Num1 + 3)%10
     << (Num2 + 3)%10
     << (Num3 + 3)%10
     << (Num4 + 3)%10
     << endl; 
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Put `int` there, you need it for the functions to compile. As far as "behaving as if `encrypt` does not exist" goes, that's because your program is crashing. Use a debugger to figure out what's going on (hint: look at this `return 0;` statement inside `readNumber` function).

Comment: You need to *pay attention to compiler warnings*. They're there to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your declare functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` **without** parameters, use/call them **without** parameter, but define/implement functions **with** parameters. Thus you get the linker error with undefined functions.

When you add `int` right before function calls in `if` statements, you replace function calls with the same function declarations like you did it before `main`.

Probably you want

```
// before main
int encrypt(int number);
int decrypt (int number);
...
// in if statements
int number = readNumber();
encrypt(number);
...
int number = readNumber();
decrypt(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not completely produce a program because the forward declarations

```
using namespace std;

int readNumber();
int encrypt();
int decrypt();
...
```

do not match the functions implemented below so the compiler can find the forward-declared

```
int encrypt();
int decrypt();
```

but the linker can only find the

```
int encrypt(int number)
```

and

```
int decrypt(int number)
```

implemented below.

But

```
if (choice == '1')
{
    int readNumber();
    int encrypt();
}
```

will compile because it does nothing. It declares functions rather than calling them. It effectively repeats what you did up at the top of the file

You want to declare

```
using namespace std;

int readNumber();
int encrypt(int number);
int decrypt(int number);
...
```

to match the functions implemented below and then

```
int toBeEncrypted = readNumber();
int encryptedNumber = encrypt(toBeEncrypted);
```

to call the functions and make use of the values they return.

Addendum: Check the return values in all of your functions. You seem to always return zero.